# Is there a way to check data usage per app on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, unix, data-transfer

In Windows 10 I can get to this screen:

[image]

It tells me the data usage of each process so I can identify which programs are using the most data (opposed to just the total bytes tx/rx for all traffic in ifconfig, etc.)

Is there a way to get similar information on *nix?

Comment: The simplest solution is to put everything you want to measure (a single app with many processes, many apps...) in a network namespace, wire this namespace up to the main namespace and measure network traffic between those namespaces with the built-in counters (ifconfig etc.)

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396193/193028) has a script to get your started. There's also tutorials on how to use network namespaces; google.

Comment: i think you can try whatpulse , check this out https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1700/application-to-show-software-usage-on-linux